# git error "could not lock config file .git/config permission denied"

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I'm developing on aws ec2, and installed git flow.
And I commanded

```
git flow init
```

Then, error happened.

```
Which branch should be used for bringing forth production releases?
   - master
Branch name for production releases: [master] master
error: could not lock config file .git/config: permission denied
Branch name for "next release" development: [develop] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: permission denied
fatal: Unable to create '/var/www/html/dev1/tomato/.git/index.lock': permission denied

How to name your supporting branch prefixes?
Feature branches? [feature/] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: permission denied
Release branches? [release/] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: permission denied
Hotfix branches? [hotfix/] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: permission denied
Support branches? [support/] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: permission denied
Version tag prefix? [] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: permission denied
```

Why I cannot success to git flow init??

Comment: I tried it, but if I use sudo, I cannot use git flow command. Do you know why I cannot use git flow command if I'm root user

Comment: Try maybe: `sudo chmod 777 .git/config` where the `.git` folder is located.

Comment: I try it, but still cannot do it. In addition to that, I notice I cannot command `git branch xxxx` to make new branch as ec2-user(normal user).

Comment: If you run `ls -al .git`, does anything look unusual? You apparently don't have write permissions on the `config` file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have an %HOME% environment variable defined.

If that variable exists and refers to H:\ (instead of %USERPROFILE%), then it will look for the global git config file in H:.gitconfig (meaning %HOME%.gitconfig).

Changing that %HOME% variable to a local path like %USERPROFILE% would solve that issue.